# C# WebBrowser Control Globalization

Tags: c#, browser, controls, culture

I am making an application in C# using the WebBrowser control.
Problem is i am not from an english speaking country and that control seams to send an english language instead of Current Culture.

So for example, sites like google will always show up in english instead of portuguese, as it appears in IE, FF, Chrome or Opera.

Is there a way to change that control's page request culture to the current system's culture, or any arbitrary culture for that matter?

Comment: Have you made sure to localize your winform: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y99d1cd3%28v=VS.100%29.aspx ?

Comment: yes - didn't change anything regarding this. tried with currentculture and currentuiculture

Comment: It is determined by Accept-Language in the http request header.  WebBrowser doesn't change this.  Maybe Visual Studio while you're debugging, there is no Portuguese version of it.  Check the language bar.

Comment: If by Language bar you mean the windows keyboard language bar, it's set to PT Português (portugal) - wich is correct. But that only pertains to keyboard anyway so it should be irrelevant. Also the webbrowser shows english even running the Release build from outside VS

Comment: I wonder what your locale settings are. This says that your locale settings determine what is rendered. http://support.microsoft.com/Default.aspx?scid=kb%3ben-us%3b889834&x=18&y=19

Comment: And yet i have Windows in portuguese, keyboard portuguese, all portuguese but it's sending default english on the accept-language apparently - will do some tests with fiddler and see what i find there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried various means to solve this problem with little success.

The Accept-Language header seems to be hard-wired to use the culture configured in the user's  Internet Settings. If you supply a value in the additionalHeaders parameter to WebBrowser.Navigate, this value will be overridden.

If you change this, your WebBrowser control should send the correct language.

I've also found a registry setting:
HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Software/Microsoft/Internet Explorer/International/AcceptLanguage

Changing this registry setting should also modify the WebBrowser control's Accept-Language header.

Unfortunately in my case, I want to be able to override the setting in a particular instance of the WebBrowser control and not modify global settings which may be used by other applications. So this approach is of no use. However, perhaps it will help you.

Comment: Hi Kedj - Like you i am weary about changing global configurations on clients machines relating to web browsing as that afects more than just my app - but thanks for the info - worth looking into

Comment: I ended up deciding to just ignore this issue - but since @kadj was the only one to answer  and his answer works i will pick it as correct