# Web Browser ActiveX login pop up translation

Tags: web, internationalization, webbrowser-control, activex

I'm using the Microsoft Web browser in a desktop application.
When I'm hitting a website needing authetification I would like to "*parametrize*" the message of the login window.
Is there a way od doing it?
Regards

Comment: Sure.  Do you mean you own the website and you want to parametrize it's login window?  Or you want to dynamically translate some text on someone else's web site?  (hint: first one is easy, second one is hard)

Comment: I don't own the site but the login pop up is not a window produced by the web site it is the authenfication of the browser....

Comment: you should be able to localize everything... what IDE are you using? VS? version?  do you have some example code where you open your browser and url?

Comment: I found a post that may answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7953102/c-sharp-webbrowser-control-globalization

Comment: I'm using the ActiveX with Windev. I'm still looking and digging in your information

Comment: In fact Even if IE (not the active x, the normal browser)menu are in french the authentication pop up is also in english...)

Comment: Ah, strange; is that the same message for all websites?  Maybe you could try a couple different versions of IE.  That's about all I can advise.

Comment: Thanks. Anyway It's just cosmetic. I will let you know if I find something. I get higher priority