# How to change default language of Web Browser control

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a trouble with a WPF application. The application uses a web browser to display a certain page (Internet Explorer). The problem is the inner browser of the application shows the page always with a language configuration in English, regardless of the configuration of the browser.
When Im testing the application, It takes the language features of the browser; but before it compiles it changes and uses English language.

Is there a way to change the default language? How can I set it to use the language defined in the browser?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11576346/1271037

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand fine your problem, but WPF is known that ignores the "culture".
I solve with this trick:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        FrameworkElement.LanguageProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(FrameworkElement), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.IetfLanguageTag)));
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! Unfortunately, it didn't work. I have already tried to change the culture, but that didn't work neither. The application uses "es-MX" language configuration, and the web browser use that configuration too. But when I compile and execute the application, it always use the "en-EN" in the inner browser. But It only happens with the executable file; if I work with Visual Studio, the language configuration remains.

Comment: My suggest, must active like first thing, then in App class. Do you tried so?

Comment: I tried that today, but didn't work neither. I insert several flags in my code (MessageBox), to watch the language/culture in different moments of the application, and always shows the right configuration. I don´t understand where the code changes the configuration.

Comment: The application uses a WebBrowser control, and I think the problem could be there. Any suggestion for setting the language in that control, please?